# Given a list of paths through a graph, efficiently find the ones that use each edge

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, memory-efficient

I have a graph and a list of paths in this graph.  For each edge `e`, I need to find the paths that use `e`, then do some other work based on these paths.  The size of the graph and a restriction on memory usage are such that I can't just iterate once over all of the paths building up an array of sets, where set `i` contains the paths that use edge `i`.

The brute force approach that will work is:

```
for edge in edges:
    x = []
    for path in paths:
        if edge in path:
          x.append(path)
    f(x)
```

How can I get better time efficiency while maintaining memory efficiency?

Comment: Can you even keep the graph itself on memory?

Comment: Yes, the graph and paths fit in memory.

Comment: Approximately what are the numbers? Can you give us approximate upper bounds on the following: 1. How many vertices in the graph? 2. How many edges in the graph? 3. How many paths? 4. How many edges typically in a path?

Comment: 40 000 vertices, 80 000 edges, 300 000 paths, paths typically have a few hundred edges

Answer (score 1):

Your specification is not clear. Where do you get the graph and the path from? Are they already pre-calculated and stored in a disk? Do you need to maintain the path set for all edges in the graph in the RAM at the same time or can you process them one by one, and then release the memory? Do you store copies of the path when you create the sets or can you index into a single copy?

If you do not have enough RAM you could use some data-structures which operate on disks. The [STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/) library is one such library.

Comment: The graph and paths are precomputed and stored in memory.  The path sets for each edge can be processed one at a time, releasing the memory.  There is no need to copy the paths; I can refer to them by index.